# How to make .htacess apply all subdirectories in the root?

Tags: .htaccess

```
$ ls
Layouts    Pictures  index.html
$ cat .htaccess
RewriteEngine On

#REDIRECT pages that are not specifically redirected
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mySite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mySite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Some redirections here

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mySite.com/
DirectoryIndex index.html wrongWay.html Layouts/wrongWay.html

IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes
$ ls Pictures
A B C D E F G
```

If user access `Pictures/A/` -directory-listing, I want that the user will see the `wrongWay.html` or `Layouts/wrongWay.html` because the dir `Pictures/A` does not cotain `index.html`. My zeroth idea was the not-working .htaccess above. Then, my first idea was `$ find . -type d -exec cp .htaccess '{}' \;` but then I also need `$ find . -type d -exec cp Layouts/wrongWay.html '{}' \;` and `$ find . -type d -exec cp Pictures/wrongWay.png '{}' \;` -- and besides that I need to fix some paths/etc-dummy, reuse to the dogs. Now I want some simple way to accomplish this. Look I have working .htaccess for one directory in the root level but now I need just a command to make it apply all subdirectories, which cmd and how?

Comment: Could you include that .htaccess file in question?

Comment: @kupson: added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a correct local URL.

As defined in your .htaccess file apache would look for `Pictures/A/index.html` then `Pictures/A/wrongWay.html` then `Pictures/A/Layouts/wrongWay.html`.

Your fix is to provide a suitable local URL so that apache can find it e.g. if your `Layouts` directory is at `http://mysite.com/Layouts` then

```
DirectoryIndex index.html wrongWay.html /Layouts/wrongWay.html
```

would work as you expect.